# Real Analysis proof check : proof divisibility

Tags: real-analysis

My Problem :

Let $n$ be in natural numbers

"$P(n) : 3n + 2$ is divisible by $3$". Show that $P(n+1)$ is true if we assume $P(n)$ to be true. Can the statement ( $P(n)...$ ) then be proven with induction?

So a two part problem.

My solution : $P(n+1) = 3n + 1 + 2 = 3n + 3$

Now here, we see that $3n$ is divisible by $3$, divided into equal parts, each part being 1 $n$, now $+ 3$ here means that we simply increase each of these groups size by $+ 1$. So $P(n+1)$ is divisible by $3$, each group being $n+1$.

The original statement $P(n)$, cant be proven with induction because the base case would be : 
$3\cdot 1 + 2 = 5$, which is not divisible by $3$.

Do you think this proof is sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake. Notice $P(n+1) = 3(n+1) + 2 = 3n + 3 + 2$. You know $3n + 2 $ is divisible by $3$ by induction hypothesis. So, $3n + 2 = 3k$ for some $k$. Hence $P(n+1)= 3k + 3 = 3(k+1)$ must be divisible by $3$. The result now follows.

Comment: This is pretty confusing since the statement isn't true at all. The induction step doesn't matter if the base case doesn't hold (which it doesn't for any n). I think pointing out the fact the OP didn't use the function correctly was good, but the rest (3n+2 is divisible by 3... to the end) is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

The induction step proceeds by showing that $P(n)$ increases by $3$ when $n$ increases by $1$, so $P(n+1)$ is divisible by $3$ if $P(n)$ is since the difference is $3$. The base case doesn't hold though: For $n = 1$ you get $P(n) = 5$ which is not divisible by $3$.